# How can I process a specific query in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my viewset, I have given filterset_fields to query the model through an API endpoint. I want to convert the retrieved queryset to a dataframe for processing the data in the model using pandas. For this, I used the `django-pandas`'s  `to_dataframe()` method.

Following are the Viewset and the function used in the viewset:

```py
class StockPriceDataViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = StockPriceData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockPriceDataSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = {
        'date':['gte','lte'],
        'org__symbol':['exact'],
        'org__group':['exact'],
    }
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
        
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_path='stock')
    def get_df(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset
        result = generate_df(queryset=queryset)
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```py
def generate_df(queryset):
    df = queryset.to_dataframe()
    df = df.drop(['s_n','id'], axis=1)
    result = df.to_json(orient='records', date_unit='ms', lines=True).splitlines()
    return result
```

In an interactive shell when I filter the queryset for specific values it works fine. What am I doing wrong here? The queryset filtering doesn't work on the API endpoint for `get_df()` while it works normally for the queryset method.

Also, the data is not being paginated for the get_df() method. What can I do here to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `self.queryset` in your method which you have set to `StockPriceData.objects.all()`, and do no filtering or pagination on that. Change your method to do those tasks:

```
def get_df(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    paginator = self.paginator
    page = None
    if paginator:
        paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
        page = paginator.page # assuming PageNumberPagination
    if page is not None:
        result = generate_df(queryset=page.object_list)
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    result = generate_df(queryset=queryset)
    return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```